# Multiplying large vectors and Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication, out-of-memory

Actually this is what i am trying to do Ad=<100820x20164 double> and b= <100820x1 double> also Ad is sparse matrix and b is non-sparse .Below is the original Problem and i try to change the statement A=V'*V + y_0*y_0'; using the block processing technique as you told me , now the problem is on the assignment statement mentioned below.

```
V=Ad;     
b_1=b;
x_0=ones(size(V ,1) ,1);
y_0=V'*x_0;
A=V'*V + y_0*y_0';
b=V'*b_1 + dot(x_0,b_1)*y_0;
```

%%%%%%%%% Modified  using block processing below %%%%%%

```
V=Ad;     
b_1=b;
x_0=ones(size(V ,1) ,1);
y_0=V'*x_0;

v=V'*V ;   %%% v is updated here which is left hand side of equation 

 %%% Block Processing code %% For right hand side of equation
 y_01 = y_0(1:size(y_0)/2);
 y_02 = y_0(size(y_0)/2 + 1:end);


 res =( y_01 * y_01'); % Upper left 
 Temp=v(1:size(v ,1)/2 , 1:size(v ,1)/2)  + res  ;
 v(1:size(v ,1)/2 , 1:size(v ,1)/2)  = Temp;       %%%% Problem here gets hang
 clear Temp; clear res ;


 res = y_02 * y_02'; % Bottom right
 Temp=v(size(v ,1)/2 + 1 :end , size(v ,1)/2 + 1 :end)  + res  ;  
 v(size(v ,1)/2 + 1:end , size(v ,1)/2 + 1:end)  = Temp; 
 clear Temp; clear res ;


 res = y_01 * y_02'; % Upper right
 Temp=v(1:size(v ,1)/2 , size(v ,1)/2 + 1:end)  + res  ;
 v(1:size(v ,1)/2 , size(v ,1)/2 + 1:end)  = Temp; 
 clear Temp; clear res ;


 res = y_02 * y_01'; % Bottom left   
 Temp=v(size(v ,1)/2 + 1:end, 1:size(v ,1)/2 )   + res  ;
 v(size(v ,1)/2 + 1:end, 1:size(v ,1)/2 )  = Temp; 
 clear Temp; clear res ;
```

Comment: It results in a 20k X 20k matrix which is about 1.5GB. What do you expect? You can try splitting your problem to smaller ones or using variables smaller than `double`

Comment: Well, it certainly is a big matrix with approx `4e8` elements, which requires about 3GB memory. The simple answer is to increase memory. Are you sure you wanted to take the outer product and not the inner? Even if you did want to take the outer product, could you explain what it is that you're trying to do? Perhaps there are better ways of doing the same.

Comment: Thanks Albert well i have updated my question now and it is clear now please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

While `V'*V` is sparse, `y_0*y_0'` is not. Unless of course `V'` has many empty rows. 
You could calculate `y_0*y_0'` block-wise:

```
y_01 = y_0(1:10000);
y_02 = y_0(10001:end);

res = y_01 * y_01' % Upper left 
% Process...
res = y_02 * y_02' % Bottom right
% Process...
res = y_01 * y_02' % Upper right
% Process...
res = y_02 * y_01' % Bottom left  
% Process...
```

In the 'Process' section you can combine it with the appropriate portion of `V'*V`. I would also suggest re-factoring my code snippet to avoid redundancy.

Comment: Thanks for this great idea i implement this but now problem i am facing is on the process section where i add the calculated result but it is taking so much time that my system get hangs what is better approach in this situation, can you provide me little example of all this by taking dummy values and how to handle the  process section in better way so that it become fast.

Comment: Please post your new code with the problematic section so it would be easier to address. Besides, it should take time as you deal with huge arrays.

Comment: Thanks Albert ,i have implemented the block processing just like you guide me but the problem is on equation v(1:size(v ,1)/2 , 1:size(v ,1)/2) = Temp; every where in code it is taking so much time now that my system hangs, code is posted please help.

Comment: I can't see where you pre-allocate `v`. In any case you should run into out-of-memory error again as `v` is too large.

Comment: Thanks Albert , yes i forget to paste v now it  is there , yes u are right the problem is that v is too large and also it is sparse that's because it is taking so much time for this assignment statement, is there any other technique for solving this problem i desperately need this equation please help.