# Multiplying two large matrices in matlab produces out of memory error

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication, out-of-memory

I have two large matrices that I need to multiply:

A x D

where A = 2358048 x 1
      B = 1 x 492020

I understand that multiplication requires enourmous amoun of RAM and this is why I get Out of Memory in matlab (I have 90GB of RAM available on the server).

Is there a way to do in in few steps. Maybe break it down some how and save pieces in some files and do multiplication step by step. Then in the end combine it all together? Sample matlab code would be most valuable. Thanks

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7861709/97160

Answer (score 8):

The full product is going to be 2358048 x 492020, meaning it has 1,160,206,776,960 elements. If you store those in float32, that's over 4 terabytes of data. Are you sure you need the full matrix? You're certainly not going to load it in RAM, anyway.

Since it's just an outer product of two enormous vectors, though, it's pretty easy to find any given subelement on demand: if C = AB, then `C(i, j) = A(i, 1) * B(1, j)`. Most things that you need to do with the matrix can then probably be done like that, maybe computing blocks of the product as needed on the fly, rather than storing the whole huge thing.

What do you need to use the product for?

If for some reason you do need the entire enormous thing written out to disk, it's pretty easy to either loop over A and write a row at a time to some file (just `A(i,1) * B`), or over B and write a column at a time (`B(1,i) * A`).

Comment: as I noted, that I understand memory issue. I need a workaround for it. Maybe there is a way to break it up in smaller chunks somehow

Comment: You said you "understand that multiplication requires enourmous amoun of RAM". But ignoring the multiplication process, the *final result* is going to be enormous, and it's not going to remotely fit into your machine's RAM. So anything involving "in the end combine it all together?" is not going to work. It is pretty easy to break up, though, as I noted in my answer: exactly how depends on what you need to do with the final matrix.

Comment: Thanks. I am using it for prediction analysis. Essentialy I have a large 5D tensor (308 x 22 x 29 x 12 x 492020) that I decomposed. I then try reconstructing it by multiplying decomposed dimensions together. In the last step I matricezed my tensor to be able to multiply it by last dimension 1 x 492020. Once it is multiplied I need to convert product back to tensor somehow. Any thoughts?

Comment: How did you have the tensor stored in the first place, since it itself is 4 terabytes? Or are you trying to generate it from some components this way? In any case, an explicit full representation of the tensor in RAM is going to be impossible, and if this factorization works I'd recommend just leaving it as-is and computing subblocks as necessary.

Comment: It saves fine in matlab. I am using tensor toolbox. I had no issues creating tensor from csv file. It took only 4 minutes to decompose on the HPC server. Moreover, multiplying first four dimensions together in reconstruction process has no issues either. It is the last step that fails.

Comment: It's not surprising that the first four dimensions have no problem, since they only have 2 million elements (rather than a quadrillion). What does the CSV you're making it from look like? Presumably it's not terabytes big (actually much larger, because CSV is very inefficient for storing numbers); I guess this means your tensor must be factorized somehow, and you'll probably want to store it in the way you're storing it originally. How are you reading it in, and what does the original file look like?